# break not working in recv() loop linux c

Tags: c, linux, loops, send, recv

I have a problem with a linux c application.
Client side users can read, send and delete messages from/to  other users logged on the system.

My problem is during the list message function:

SERVER SIDE CODE

```
 if (strcmp(buffer, "list_messages") == 0) { 
     rewind(messages); // messages is the name of the file where messages are stored
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), messages) != NULL) {
send(client_sock, line, strlen(line), 0);
    }
puts("all message sended");     }
```

CLIENT SIDE CODE

```
if (ch == 1) { // 1 is the choose from a menu where u can choose what u wanna do ( read, list etc) 
  clearConsole();
 puts("MESSAGES LIST.\n");
 strcpy(buffer, "list_messages");
 send(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0); // tell to the server that we want to read messages
 memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
  do{
    nBytes = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0 );
     if (nBytes < 0 || nBytes == 0) break;                                            
       buffer[nBytes]='\0';
       printf("%s", buffer);
      }while(nBytes > 0);
       puts("i'm out");
```

It work except one thing: on server side i can read the output "all messages sended"
so on client side i can see all messages,   but i never saw the "i'm out" message, in fact i can only use ctrl+c and exit from the application.

If i change

```
 if (nBytes < 0 || nBytes == 0) break;
```

with

```
if (nBytes > 0 || nBytes == 0) break;
```

i return to the menu, and i can choose another option,  but messages are not listed.

thank u very much for helping me. Maybe it sounds like a stupid question, but Linux c programming is not my field  ( and as u can read, english isn't too XD )

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the sending side never closes the socket? If that's the case, your `recv` is probably blocking on a "next line" that never comes.

Comment: thanks for the answeer danfuzz. i need the socket's remain active to handle user's other choose in the menu. Do u know another way to break the loop without close socket?

Comment: You might have to define a higher level protocol, e.g. define messages as having an "opcode" (such as "print this line" or "done printing") and an optional payload, etc. etc. I think it goes beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: An interesting thing: if i kill the server ( ctrl-c) the client exit from loop and return to the menu ( that's what i want). it's clear that u are right danfuzz. Has  send() some flag or some other way to notify the rcv() that its sending data is over?

Comment: The main way at the socket layer is really to close the socket. TCP supports some signalling stuff too, but it's usually to be avoided. Really, I think you need to define a real protocol / format within the stream. There are libraries that can help with this (e.g. Thrift or protocol buffers), though it may be overkill for your need.